# Limiting my float to only 3 DIGITS

Tags: c

Hi i would like to check how i can limit the number of digits for my float value to only 3 digits. Basically the following is my code for sum and average age. Sum is in integer while average is in float. But i want to limit it to only 3 digits for my average age. I tried using the %.2f but if the average age is more than 10 then i will have 4 digits in my final answer. Please help me out. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
printf("The total age of the 5 individuals are %d\n", sum);
printf("The average age of the 5 individuals are %.2f", average);
```

Answer (score 0):

The %.2f means 2 digits after the comma.
Maybe there is something better but it works :

```
float average = 10,1498; //Example

if (average < 10) {
  printf("The average age of the 5 individuals are %.2f", average);
else
  printf("The average age of the 5 individuals are %.1f", average);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Limiting my float to only 3 DIGITS

By limit, I assume printing 10.0 as "10" meets the goal as the digits count is *limited* to 3 (as an upper bound).

Step 1 print the number with 3 significant digits using `"%e"` to a string.

```
char buf[20];
sprintf(buf, "%0.2e", average);
```

Step 2 Convert that string to a `double`.

```
atof(buf);
```

Step 3 Print using "%g" as that will not print unneeded trailing zeros

```
char buf[20];
sprintf(buf, "%0.2e", 1.234); printf("average %g\n", atof(buf));
sprintf(buf, "%0.2e", 1.236); printf("average %g\n", atof(buf));
sprintf(buf, "%0.2e", 9.994); printf("average %g\n", atof(buf));
sprintf(buf, "%0.2e", 9.997); printf("average %g\n", atof(buf));
sprintf(buf, "%0.2e",10.04); printf("average %g\n", atof(buf));
sprintf(buf, "%0.2e",12.345); printf("average %g\n", atof(buf));
```

Output

```
average 1.23
average 1.24
average 9.99
average 10
average 10
average 12.3
```

This approach though may not meets OP goal if the average is < 1 like 0.123

---

Be careful trying to otherwise do the rounding with text processing on a string.  The edge cases near 9.99x and 99.9x are challenging to do only using text manipulations.

A numeric solution could use, but may not work as desired for values *very* close to the limits and depending on the current rounding mode.

```
if (average < 9.995) {
  digs = 2;
} else if (average < 99.95) {
  digs = 1;
} else  {
  digs = 0;

printf("The average age of the 5 individuals are %.*f", digs, average);
```

Attempting to round and then print  `average` via code like `if (average < 9.995) { average = round(average*100)/100; printf("%.2f", average);` can suffer the same problem for values very near the boundaries.